# How do I add audio programmatically to a Toast notification?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I had code like the following:

```
ToastNotifier ToastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
XmlNodeList toastNodeList = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
toastNodeList.Item(0).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(title));
toastNodeList.Item(1).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(stringContent));
XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Alarm7");
audio.SetAttribute("loop", "false");
```

However, testing this with:

```
toastXml.GetXml();
```

shows that the audio doesn't get added to the xml. How do I get it to be added. The docs for audio are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/tiles/toastschema/element-audio) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using Windows 10 we strongly recommend using the Notifications library. See the [official documentation showing how to add audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/custom-audio-on-toasts) to toasts.

Your code looks quite cleaner using the Notifications library

```
ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
{
    Visual = new ToastVisual()
    {

    },

    Audio = new ToastAudio()
    {
        Src = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/CustomToastAudio.m4a")
    };
};
```

But if you prefer using the XML DOM manually, or have to target Windows 8, **the mistake is that you never added the audio element.** See the last line below.

```
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
...
XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Alarm7");
audio.SetAttribute("loop", "false");

// Add the audio element
toastXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(audio);
```

Comment: I actually added that line and got an exception.

Comment: Ah try `toastXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(audio)`